# Refactoring Java 8 stream code - duplication of code

Tags: java-8, stream, refactoring

I have two methods which are nearly the same:

```
public String find(Query query) {
        return PRODUCT.stream()
                .filter(byName(query.getName()))
                .filter(byCount(query.getNumber()))
                .map(getValueOf(query.getName()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException());
    }
```

and second:

```
public String findSpecial(Query query) {
        return SPECIAL_PRODUCTS.stream()
                .filter(byName(query.getName()))
                .filter(byCount(query.getNumber()))
                .filter(byIsDoubled(query.isDoubled()))
                .map(getValueOf(query.getName()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException());
    }
```

so the difference is only line `.filter(byIsDoubled(query.isDoubled()))`.

Is there a good way to not duplicate methods body?

Comment: Sometimes duplicate some lines is not bad.

Comment: @YCF_L But I am duplicating 5 lines and only adding `filter`. It doesn't looks good for me

Comment: You can design something like  `filter(!isSpecial || byIsDoubled(query.isDoubled()))` which return true if `isSpecial` is false and pass like `find(Query query, boolean isSpecial)` though I agree with @YCF_L and sometimes clean code is better than making complex to remove duplicate lines.

Comment: Do like this: `public String find(Query query, List<Product> list,List<Predicate<Product>> predicates){
       return list.stream().filter(product -> predicates.stream()
                .allMatch(productPredicate -> productPredicate.test(product)))
                .map(getValueOf(query.getName()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(IllformedLocaleException::new);
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
SPECIAL_PRODUCTS.stream().filter(findConditional(query)).map(getValueOf(query.getName()))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException());



public static Predicate<String> findConditional(Query query) {
        List<Predicate<String>> l = new ArrayList<>();
        Predicate<String> defaultPredicate = s -> true;
        l.add(byName(query.getName()));
        l.add(byCount(query.getNumber()));
        if (query.isDoubled()) {
            l.add(byIsDoubled(query.isDoubled()));
        }
        return l.stream().reduce(defaultPredicate, (predicate1, predicate2) -> predicate1.and(predicate2));
    }
```